# Cross origin não esta funcionando com angulasJS e PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, cors

Estou tentando fazer o download de um arquivo através do angularJS gerando em uma página php:

#### Página PHP

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

include('conn.php');

$arquivo = 'Contratos_Pendentes.xls';

$tabela = '<table border="1">';
$tabela .='<tr>';
$tabela .='<td colspan="5">Contratos Pendentes</tr>';
$tabela .='</tr>';
$tabela .='<tr>';
$tabela .='<td><b>Corretor</b></td>';
$tabela .='<td><b>Cliente</b></td>';
$tabela .='<td><b>CPF</b></td>';
$tabela .='<td><b>Numero Contrato</b></td>';
$tabela .='<td><b>Fisico</b></td>';
$tabela .='</tr>';

$resultado = mysql_query('SELECT A.NOME_CORRETOR as corretor, A.CPF_CONTRATO as cpf, A.NUMERO_CONTRATO as numero_contrato, A.FISICO as fisico, B.NOME as cliente, B.CPF as cpf2 FROM CONTRATO A JOIN CLIENTE B ON A.CPF_CONTRATO = B.CPF AND A.FISICO = "PENDENTE" ');

while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
{
$tabela .='<tr>';
$tabela .='<td>'.$dados['corretor'].'</td>';
$tabela .='<td>'.$dados['cliente'].'</td>';
$tabela .='<td>'.$dados['cpf'].'</td>';
$tabela .='<td>'.$dados['numero_contrato'].'</td>';
$tabela .='<td>'.$dados['fisico'].'</td>';
$tabela .='</tr>';
}
$tabela .='</table>';

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$arquivo);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($arquivo));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');

readfile($arquivo);

echo $tabela;
```

#### AngularJs

```
 $scope.GerarPlanilha = function (){
$http({
            url: 'localhost:8080/ltfinaceira/php/RelatorioFisico.php',
            method: 'POST',
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
            }
        }).success(function(data){
            var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});
            saveAs(blob, file_name_to_be+'.xlsx');
        }).error(function(){

        });
    };
```

Mas eu recebo o seguinte erro

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8080/ltfinaceira/php/RelatorioFisico.php. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'localhost:8080/ltfinaceira/php/RelatorioFisico.php'.
```

Comment: O arquivo REALMENTE está em : `localhost:8080/ltfinaceira/php/RelatorioFisico.php` ?????

Comment: Boa tarde, algumas das respostas lhe resolveu o problema?

Comment: Boa noite, gostaria de saber se alguma das respostas lhe ajudou, se não por favor comente o que acha que falta.

Answer (score 2):

Voce usou `localhost:8080` o certo seria `http://localhost:8080`, da maneira que voce fez, omitindo o http o ajax esta pensa que `localhost` e o *protocolo* e o `8080` e o *host*.

E outro detalhe, parece `file_name_to_be` não foi definida por você, então defina um valor (não sei exatamente de onde vem o nome do arquivo)

Faca assim:

```
 $scope.GerarPlanilha = function (){
      var file_name_to_be = "meu_arquivo";
      $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/ltfinaceira/php/RelatorioFisico.php',
            method: 'POST',
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
            }
        }).success(function(data){
            var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});
            saveAs(blob, file_name_to_be+'.xlsx');
        }).error(function(){

        });
    };
```

Comment: agora estou recebendo este erro ReferenceError: file_name_to_be is not defined

Comment: @LuizFábio isto ja e outro problema. Esta variavel ou objeto `file_name_to_be ` nao esta no codigo. Por favor crie uma nova pergunta se for um problema muito longe do atual, no entanto se nao for voce pode editar a pergunta.

Comment: @LuizFábio Editei a pergunta e adicionei um exemplo sobre o problema com `file_name_to_be`, teste por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez estes comandos possam te ajudar a "desbarrar" o acesso à pastas ao iniciar o navegador:

**Windows:**

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

ou

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```

**Mac:**

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ --args --allow-file-access-from-files
```